# Vb: How can I select more than one file directory?

Tags: vb.net, search, directory

Here is the code :

```
 Try
        For Each strDir As String In
        System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.ProgramFiles)
            For Each strFile As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDir)

               ListBox1.Items.Add(strFile)

            Next

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

The problem is where it says (My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.ProgramFiles) I want it to look there and here: (My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.temp)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop through each one separately; you can't do it in one single call.  Try this:

```
For Each strRootDir In {My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.ProgramFiles, My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp}
    For Each strDir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(strRootDir)
        For Each strFile As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDir)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(strFile)
        Next
    Next
Next
```